# Is there a way to check for two different patterns in the same string in regex python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract certain digits from a string. The problem is that the string can contain the digits in two different patterns. How can I create a regex pattern in `re.search` such that I can have both patterns to search in a single string?

For e.g.,

```
## extract 65.45 from this string
string = '1112 (65.45%)'
```

So, if I do the following, it works

```
re.search('.*?\((.*)%\)', string).group(1)
```

and I get the expected result `65.45`.

Now, I have another kind of string in the same text that I need to look for.

```
## from this string, extract 4.00 which appears before [
string = '4.00 [3.00 - 4.50]'

re.search('^(\S+)\s\[.*', string).group(1)
```

gives me the desired result: 4.00

But if I combine them like the following, it only extracts the one that matches first.

```
re.search('^(\S+)\s\[.*|.*?\((.*)%\)', string).group(1)
```

in which case, only the string that contains the square bracket extracts the value, not if the string has a % sign. How can I fix this?

For e.g., If I have a list of strings like the following:

```
['73 (1.40%)', '38 (1.55%)', '27 (2.17%)', '32 (1.46%)', '10 (1.46%)', '11 (1.04%)', '11 (1.41%)', '7 (1.34%)', '4 (1.24%)', '28 (1.27%)', '750 (14.41%)', '381 (15.54%)', '182 (14.60%)', '313 (14.27%)', '4.10 [3.73 - 4.45]', '4.08 [3.70 - 4.42]', '4.13 [3.77 - 4.47]', '4.13 [3.78 - 4.47]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.42]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.43]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.40]', '4.09 [3.73 - 4.42]', '4.03 [3.63 - 4.40]', '4.10 [3.70 - 4.47]']
```

I want to do certain things with each value that is extracted and compare with a specific threshold value.

Using the for-loop, I did something like this:

```
for val in string: 
    match = re.search('^(\S+)\s\[.*|.*?\((.*)%\)', val)
    print(match)
```

which results in the following:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='73 (1.40%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='38 (1.55%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='27 (2.17%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='32 (1.46%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='10 (1.46%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='11 (1.04%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='11 (1.41%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='7 (1.34%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='4 (1.24%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='28 (1.27%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='750 (14.41%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='381 (15.54%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='182 (14.60%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='313 (14.27%)'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.10 [3.73 - 4.45]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.08 [3.70 - 4.42]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.13 [3.77 - 4.47]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.13 [3.78 - 4.47]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.07 [3.70 - 4.42]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.07 [3.70 - 4.43]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.07 [3.70 - 4.40]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.09 [3.73 - 4.42]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.03 [3.63 - 4.40]'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='4.10 [3.70 - 4.47]'>
```

But not sure how to extract the exact value.

I have to do the .group() to extract the value, but it requires me to know the exact location. And I'm struggling to figure out how to do that.

If I do `match.group(2)`, then I get the following result:

```
1.40
1.55
2.17
1.46
1.46
1.04
1.41
1.34
1.24
1.27
14.41
15.54
14.60
14.27
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Can you include a _single_ sample input containing _both_ versions of what you want to match, along with the values which are captured?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I just added a list of values that I'm trying to check against. Is this what you're asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a list of simple regexs and iterate through them for each string I want to test. The first regex that gets a hit will be used. I would also compile the regex upfront to save CPU cycles. This is easier to follow readability wise and easy to add new patterns to:

```
import re

regexs = [
    re.compile(r".*?\((.*)%\)"), 
    re.compile(r"^(\S+)\s\[.*"),
]

data = [
    "73 (1.40%)",
    "38 (1.55%)",
    "27 (2.17%)",
    "750 (14.41%)",
    "381 (15.54%)",
    "4.10 [3.73 - 4.45]",
    "4.08 [3.70 - 4.42]",
    "4.13 [3.77 - 4.47]",
    "this shouldn't match"
]


for val in data:
    for regex in regexs:
        if match := regex.search(val):
            print("Matched: " + match.group(1))
            break
    else:
        print("No match: " + val)
```

Outputs:

```
Matched: 1.40
Matched: 1.55
Matched: 2.17
Matched: 14.41
Matched: 15.54
Matched: 4.10
Matched: 4.08
Matched: 4.13
No match: this shouldn't match
```

Comment: I really like this solution as this doesn't require me to change the regex and also gives me ability to add other regex later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which works with your exact input, in which each list entry always would have one of the two matching patterns:

```py
inp = ['73 (1.40%)', '38 (1.55%)', '27 (2.17%)', '32 (1.46%)', '10 (1.46%)', '11 (1.04%)', '11 (1.41%)', '7 (1.34%)', '4 (1.24%)', '28 (1.27%)', '750 (14.41%)', '381 (15.54%)', '182 (14.60%)', '313 (14.27%)', '4.10 [3.73 - 4.45]', '4.08 [3.70 - 4.42]', '4.13 [3.77 - 4.47]', '4.13 [3.78 - 4.47]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.42]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.43]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.40]', '4.09 [3.73 - 4.42]', '4.03 [3.63 - 4.40]', '4.10 [3.70 - 4.47]']
matches = [re.findall(r'\b\d+ \((\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \[\d+(?:\.\d+)? - \d+(?:\.\d+)?\]', x) for x in inp]
matches = [x[0][0] + x[0][1] for x in matches]
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['1.40%', '1.55%', '2.17%', '1.46%', '1.46%', '1.04%', '1.41%', '1.34%',
 '1.24%', '1.27%', '14.41%', '15.54%', '14.60%', '14.27%', '4.10', '4.08',
 '4.13', '4.13', '4.07', '4.07', '4.07', '4.09', '4.03', '4.10']
```

The strategy used above is to match, in two separate groups, either the first digit in the percentage input, or the number outside the square brackets.  Then, in a list comprehension, we concatenate the two capture groups together.  Since one of the two groups is guaranteed to be empty, the concatenated result always corresponds to the desired match.

Answer (score 0):

`.group` returns captured groups, so `.group(1)` always returns the *first* captured group.

To get the other capture group, use `.group(2)`

Comment: but how can I decide which group to capture if I'm doing this in a loop. The text can appear at any run? I'm only trying to avoid conditional search for `%` or some other way if I can do this in one line

Comment: @Kuni Check the location of the parentheses in the expression. A capture group can be empty if it doesn't capture anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use lookarounds to get a match only:

```
(?<=\()\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=%\))|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*\[[^][]*])
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<=\()` Positive lookbehind, assert `(` to the left
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?=%\))` Positive lookahead, assert `)` to the right
- `|` Or
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?=\s*\[[^][]*])` Positive lookahead, assert an opening till closing square bracket to the right (You could make it more specific by specifying the exact format between the square brackets)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i2ckOY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4PfCdc)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<=\()\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=%\))|\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b(?=\s*\[[^][]*\])"
strings = ['73 (1.40%)', '38 (1.55%)', '27 (2.17%)', '32 (1.46%)', '10 (1.46%)', '11 (1.04%)', '11 (1.41%)', '7 (1.34%)', '4 (1.24%)', '28 (1.27%)', '750 (14.41%)', '381 (15.54%)', '182 (14.60%)', '313 (14.27%)', '4.10 [3.73 - 4.45]', '4.08 [3.70 - 4.42]', '4.13 [3.77 - 4.47]', '4.13 [3.78 - 4.47]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.42]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.43]', '4.07 [3.70 - 4.40]', '4.09 [3.73 - 4.42]', '4.03 [3.63 - 4.40]', '4.10 [3.70 - 4.47]']
for val in strings:
    match = re.search(pattern, val)
    print(match)
```

Output

```
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='1.40'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='1.55'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='2.17'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='1.46'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='1.46'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='1.04'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='1.41'>
<re.Match object; span=(3, 7), match='1.34'>
<re.Match object; span=(3, 7), match='1.24'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 8), match='1.27'>
<re.Match object; span=(5, 10), match='14.41'>
<re.Match object; span=(5, 10), match='15.54'>
<re.Match object; span=(5, 10), match='14.60'>
<re.Match object; span=(5, 10), match='14.27'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.10'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.08'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.13'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.13'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.07'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.07'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.07'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.09'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.03'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='4.10'>
```